# Pivot across multiple columns with repeating values in each column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to pivot a pandas dataframe, but the data is following a strange format that I cannot seem to pivot. The data is structured as below:

```
Date, Location, Action1, Quantity1, Action2, Quantity2, ... ActionN, QuantityN
<date>   1      Lights    10         CFloor     1        ...  Null     Null
<date2>  2      CFloor    2          CWalls     4        ...  CBasement 15 
<date3>  2      CWalls    7          CBasement  4        ...  NUll     Null
```

Essentially, each action will always have a quantity attached to it (which may be 0), but null actions will never have a quantity (the quantity will just be null). The format I am trying to achieve is the following:

```
       Lights    CFloor    CBasement   CWalls
1        10         1         0           0
2        0          2         19          11
```

The index of the rows becomes the location while the columns become any unique action found across the multiple activity columns. When pulling the data together, the value of each row/column is the sum of each quantity associated with the action (i.e Action1 corresponds to Quantity1). Is there a way to do this with the native pandas pivot funciton?

My current code performs a ravel across all the activity columns to get a list of all unique activities. It will also grab all the unique locations from the Location column. Once I have the unique columns, I create an empty dataframe and fill it with zeros:

```
       Lights    CFloor    CBasement   CWalls
1        0         0         0            0
2        0         0         0            0
```

I then iterate back over the old data frame with the itertuples() method (I was told it was significantly faster than iterrows()) and populate the new dataframe. This empty dataframe acts as a template that is stored in memory and filled later.

```
#Creates a template from the dataframe
def create_template(df):
    act_cols = ['Activity01', 'Activity02', 'Activity03', 'Activity04']
    activities = df[act_cols]
    flat_acts = activities.values.ravel('K')
    unique_locations = pd.unique(df['Location'])
    unique_acts = pd.unique(flat_acts)
    pivot_template = pd.DataFrame(index=unique_locations, columns=unique_acts).fillna(0)
    return pivot_template


#Fills the template from the dataframe
def create_pivot(df, pivot_frmt):
    act_cols = ['Activity01', 'Activity02', 'Activity03', 'Activity04']
    quant_cols = ['Quantity01', 'Quantity02', 'Quantity03', 'Quantity04']

    for row in df.itertuples():
        for act, quantity in zip(act_cols, quant_cols):
            act_val = getattr(row, act)
            if pd.notna(act_val):
                quantity_val = getattr(row, quantity)
                location = getattr(row, 'Location')
                pivot_frmt.loc[location, act_val] += quantity_val
    return pivot_frmt
```

While my solution works, it is incredibly slow when dealing with a large dataset and has taken 10 seconds or more to complete this type of operation. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Update: After a bit of research I found the crosstab function which appears to have the same functionality as pivot when passed values. My initial tests show it is working as I intended, but can only handle one column and value set at a time. Here is my test code: pd.crosstab(index=df['Location'], columns=df['Activity01'], values=df['Quantity01'], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)

Answer (score 1):

After experimenting with various pandas functions, such as melt and pivot on multiple columns simulatenously, I found a solution that worked for me:

For every quantity-activity pair, I build a partial frame of the final dataset and store it in a list. Once every pair has been addressed I will end up with multiple dataframes that all have the same row counts, but potentially different column counts. I solved this issue by simply concatenating the columns and if any columns are repeated, I then sum them to get the final result.

```
def test_pivot(df):
    act_cols = ['Activity01', 'Activity02', 'Activity03', 'Activity04']
    quant_cols = ['Quantity01', 'Quantity02', 'Quantity03', 'Quantity04']
    dfs = []
    for act, quant in zip(act_cols, quant_cols):
        partial = pd.crosstab(index=df['Location'], columns=df[act], values=df[quant], aggfunc=np.sum).fillna(0)
        dfs.append(partial)

    finalDf = pd.concat(dfs, axis=1)
    finalDf = test.groupby(finalDf.columns, axis=1).sum()
    return finalDf
```

There are two assumptions that I make during this approach:

1. The indexes maintain their order across all partial dataframes
2. There are an equivalent number of indexes across all partial dataframes

While this is probably not the most elegant solution, it achieves the desired result and reduced the time it took to process the data by a very significant margin (from 10s ~4k rows to 0.2s ~4k rows). If anybody has a better way to deal with this type of scenario and do the process outlined above in one shot, then I would love to see your response!